# Creating New Record Using Structure Overwrites Previous Record C++

Tags: c++, file-io, struct

I am coding in c++ and am having a problem with a specific function of my program. I am writing to the end of a file but each time I try to add a record to the file, it overwrites the previous record. After testing, I know that the specific code I am including is the code with the problem. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've looked everywhere and can't find an answer.

Also, I know the program is pretty unstructured right now. That's next on the to do list.

```
    if(userI == 1){
    infoFile.open("inventory.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
    infoFile.seekg(0, ios::end);
    cout << "Thank you for choosing to enter a new record." << endl;
    cout << "Please enter a description of the item up to 50 characters: ";
    getline(cin,description);
    strcpy(records.description, description.c_str());
    cin.clear();
    cin.sync();
    cout << "Please enter the quantity on hand: ";
    cin >> records.quantity;
    cin.clear();
    cin.sync();
    cout << "Please enter the wholesale cost of the item: ";
    cin >> records.wholesale;
    cin.clear();
    cin.sync();
    cout << "Please enter the retail cost of the item: ";
    cin >> records.retail;
    cin.clear();
    cin.sync();
    cout << "Please enter the date in the form dd/mm/yyyy: ";
    cin >> records.date;
    cin.clear();
    cin.sync();
    infoFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&infoFile), sizeof(infoFile));
    infoFile.close();
}
```

Comment: You *always* write the structure at the beginning of the file. Maybe you should write in a loop, or *append* to the file?

Comment: I've also tried using ios::app instead of ios::out in the open statement and setting the cursor to write to the end of the file with the seekg statement. The program is for a class and one of the criteria for the program states we cannot write to the file in a loop. Do you have any other ideas??

Comment: Using `ios::app` will automatically cause all writes to happen at the end of the file, no need to seek.

Comment: Read the line where you write *very carefully* and pay attention to what it is that you're writing.

Comment: I tried replacing the args in both statements in the write line with records thinking I was writing the wrong thing but that didn't work at all. IS there something more I'm missing? mobldino